# htaccess redirects incorrectly

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

hope you can help me, when i tried to access www.boxer-motors.com "articulos"/"entrevista" and then click in "seguir leyendo", should redirect to the full entrevista article, but insted redirects me to "articulos"/"editorial". Thanks in advance

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^noticias/$ /noticias/nacionales/ [R]
RewriteRule ^noticias$ /noticias/nacionales/ [R]
RewriteRule ^noticias/nacionales$ noticias.php?t=1&p=$1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^noticias/nacionales/$ noticias.php?t=1&p=$1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^noticias/nacionales/([0-9]*)$ noticias.php?t=1&p=$1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^noticias/nacionales/([0-9]*)/$ noticias.php?t=1&p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^noticias/nacionales/([^/]*)$ noticia_detalle.php?t=1&n=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^noticias/nacionales/([^/]*)/$ noticia_detalle.php?t=1&n=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^noticias/internacionales$ noticias.php?t=2&p=$1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^noticias/internacionales/$ noticias.php?t=2&p=$1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^noticias/internacionales/([0-9]*)$ noticias.php?t=2&p=$1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^noticias/internacionales/([0-9]*)/$ noticias.php?t=2&p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^noticias/internacionales/([^/]*)$ noticia_detalle.php?t=2&n=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^noticias/internacionales/([^/]*)/$ noticia_detalle.php?t=2&n=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^articulos/$ /articulos/entrevista/ [L]
RewriteRule ^articulos$ /articulos/entrevista/ [R]
RewriteRule ^articulos/([^/]*)$ articulos.php?t=$1&p=1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^articulos/([^/]*)/$ articulos.php?t=$1&p=1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^articulos/([^/]*)/([0-9]*)$ articulos.php?t=$1&p=$2 [L] 
RewriteRule ^articulos/([^/]*)/([0-9]*)/$ articulos.php?t=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^articulos/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ articulo_detalle.php?           t=$1&n=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^articulos/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ articulo_detalle.php?t=$1&n=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems not to be in your `.htaccess` file:

calling this url: http://boxer-motors.com/articulos/entrevistas/glauco-rivera/

will internally call: http://boxer-motors.com/articulo_detalle.php?t=entrevistas&n=glauco-rivera

And this second call redirects you to: http://boxer-motors.com/articulos/editorial/

When I deactivate the javascript in my browser the page load without problem, so this is a javascript related problem.

Comment: Thanks, i was crazy with that =(